# How is this chan leaked?

Tags: concurrency, go, garbage, goroutine

I'm trying to understand the problem outlined on this slide:

http://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#27

Copying the code in case the URL dies:

```
func sendMsg(msg, addr string) error {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    _, err = fmt.Fprint(conn, msg)
    return err
}

func broadcastMsg(msg string, addrs []string) error {
    errc := make(chan error)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        go func(addr string) {
            errc <- sendMsg(msg, addr)
            fmt.Println("done")
        }(addr)
    }

    for _ = range addrs {
        if err := <-errc; err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    addr := []string{"localhost:8080", "http://google.com"}
    err := broadcastMsg("hi", addr)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("everything went fine")
}
```

And the comments:

- the goroutine is blocked on the chan write
- the goroutine holds a reference to the chan
- the chan will never be garbage collected

I'm not sure I understand why the chan never gets collected or which goroutine is keeping a reference to the chan. Your time is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)
>
> A function literal represents an anonymous function.
>
> ```
> FunctionLit = "func" Function .
>
> func(a, b int, z float64) bool { return a*b < int(z) }
> ```
>
> A function literal can be assigned to a variable or invoked directly.
>
> ```
> f := func(x, y int) int { return x + y }
> func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }(replyChan)
> ```
>
> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.
>
> [Send statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)
>
> A send statement sends a value on a channel. The channel expression
>   must be of channel type, the channel direction must permit send
>   operations, and the type of the value to be sent must be assignable to
>   the channel's element type.
>
> ```
> SendStmt = Channel "<-" Expression .
> Channel  = Expression .
> ```
>
> Both the channel and the value expression are evaluated before
>   communication begins. Communication blocks until the send can proceed.
>   A send on an unbuffered channel can proceed if a receiver is ready. A
>   send on a buffered channel can proceed if there is room in the buffer.
>   A send on a closed channel proceeds by causing a run-time `panic`. A
>   send on a `nil` channel blocks forever.

There is only one `go` statement, `go func(addr string)`, and it's a closure over the channel variable `errc`.

```
func broadcastMsg(msg string, addrs []string) error {
    errc := make(chan error)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        go func(addr string) {
            errc <- sendMsg(msg, addr)
            fmt.Println("done")
        }(addr)
    }

    for _ = range addrs {
        if err := <-errc; err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Two goroutines are started since `len(addrs) == 2`. Because of a premature exit when `err != nil` on the first receive on channel `errc`, only one goroutine completes. The second goroutine is blocked on the send (write) to the unbuffered channel `errc`; it never completes. Therefore, there is still a reference to `errc`, so it's never garbage collected. The second goroutine is eventually abandoned when the program exits.